# How to rename address labels on Address field module?

Tags: forms

I wanted to know if it's possible to change the input labels on the address field module 'Address 1' and 'Address 2' without using the string overrides module?

I want to be able to change them to say 'Address line 1' and 'Address line 2'.

Can this be done in a template preprocess function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with hook_form_alter:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    //drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);

    switch($form_id) {

        case 'MY_FORM_ID':

            // dpm($form);

            // $form['NAME_OF_YOUR_FIELD'] - this is the field you want to edit

            // check that the field is set before looping over values
            if(isset($form['NAME_OF_YOUR_FIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE])) {
                // loop over each values passing $item by reference
                foreach($form['NAME_OF_YOUR_FIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE] as &$item) {
                    if(is_array($item) && isset($item['street_block'])) {
                        $item['street_block']['thoroughfare']['#title'] = 'Address Line 1';
                        $item['street_block']['premise']['#title'] = 'Address Line 2';
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

I found the path to the variable I wanted to change by outputting the $form array to the message area using [devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel)'s dpm function, and then searching though the array for the value "Address 1" using the [search krumo](https://drupal.org/project/search_krumo) module.

Comment: Hi Felix, thank you for your help. I have added this to my template file, changed MY_MODULE to my theme name and changed 'MY_FORM_ID' to 'order-form-entityform-edit-form' but the changes are not happening. I have flushed caches. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Arr - that is code for a custom module, not a template file. See [Creating Drupal 7.x modules](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7) if you need any help with that.

Comment: Form alters can be done in themes (I think any alter can).  You just have to make sure the theme is in use on the form you are altering, especially on admin forms.

Comment: I did not know that - cheers MPD.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I've looked into hook form alter and have come up with this code but it's not working. Can you help?

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function my_theme_form_order_form_entityform_edit_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

// Change labels for the 'Address 1' and 'Address 2' elements.
  $form['street_block']['thoroughfare']['#title'] = t('Address line 1');
  $form['street_block']['premise']['#title'] = t('Address line 2');
}

Comment: I actually tested the code in my answer so I know it should work. Have you made sure that you have put the correct form id where it says MY_FORM_ID? You can un-comment the line with drupal_set_message to find out the correct form ID to use.

Comment: You want to be changing values in $form['field_address'] - $form['street_block'] does not exist. Note how I'm looping over the field_address field passing each item by reference to update the values if there are multiple addresses.

Comment: Yes I changed 'MY_FORM_ID' using the form id displayed when uncommenting the line. But I got this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in my_theme_form_alter() (line 142 of C:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\themes\my-theme\template.php).

Comment: So check that $form['field_address'][LANGUAGE_NONE] is set before looping over values. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, used the new code, the error has gone but the labels are not updated Felix

Comment: Ok, you need to install the devel module as then you can use the dmp function to inspect the form array and figure out why it's not working. Try putting one call to dmp($form) before you make any changes, and then another after your code so you can see what effect it is having. Those labels are part of the array - you just need to find out what value to change and update it. Like I said my code is tested and working on my sandbox site so your already 99% of the way there.

Comment: Ar ha - also on my site my field is called field_address - it may not be called that on your site. Again using dmp will allow to to find out the correct name of your field. Alternatively you can get the name of the field by looking at your node structure page.

Comment: Ah that was it! my field was called field_postal_address. Changed that and it works great!! Thank you very much Felix :)